# extracting second digit from a number

Tags: python, pandas

In my program, I have a data file with a column processing type. This column has numbers datatypes as object. I want to write a condition that if the number has 2 as a 2nd digit , then i want to keep these records rest filtered out[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrDly.jpg)

Comment: Can you post an input dataframe with expected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = str(YOUR_NUMBER)[::-1][2]
answer = int(a[2])
```

This converts your number to a string, reverses it, and then gets the second character, and converts it back to a number. the variable `answer` contains what you want.

Comment: yeah, but i need to check this condition and if 2nd place number is two then i will keep it if not i will move on to next

Answer (score 0):

If by 'second digit' you mean the penultimate one (ex: for 1234 it would be 3)

Then you can simply do `second_digit = (n // 10) % 10` or `second_digit = int(str(n)[-2])` where n is your number

Comment: yeah, but i need to check this condition and if 2nd place number is two then i will keep it if not i will move on to next